# Ionic custom alert component template

Tags: css, templates, ionic3, customization, alert

I am trying to implement a popup dialog for my Ionic 3 up that will be used to cofirm deletion of an object from the collection.
The perfect flow I am imagining is this : 
An alert appears with a question "Delete item? Yes No" and after clicking yes, a spinner appears **inside** the alert to indicate that a request is sent to the server and pending response. After the response has been received I want the alert to smoothly change into a confirmation alert, something like this:
[image]

Unfortunately I found out that it is impossible to provide custom templates for alert components in ionic. From what I've read it seems like the only option is to create a modal with a custom template instead. The problem is, however, that the model opens full-screen and I want a nice little alert with the backdrop in the background.
Can you please give me some advice on how to achieve this?

Question 2: I really like the design of the confirmation alert that I have posted above :) Any advice on how to make it?

Cheers guys, as always - thank you!

Comment: i think you can show popover component of ionic